# Optimal Value & Uniform Distribution

Tags: calculus, functions, uniform-distribution

In a simple setting, $w$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, R is a function of $wd$.
I want to find optimal d in this expression,

$aR-(d^2-1)/2$.

When I try to find out optimal $d$ than it is $0$. But i think I am ignoring the fact that $R$ is a function of $wd$ but what form it is, is not known. Does this change the solution of this problem.

Guidelines will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Will it be fine if I replace $R$ with $dw$ in above equation. But i don't think that will be correct as $R$ is function of $wd$.

Answer (score 0):

If $R$ is a function of $wd$ then presumably $\mathbb{E}[aR]$ is not a constant, 
so its derivative of with respect to $d$ is not zero, 
with the consequence that your second and third lines are not helpful.

To actually find optimal $d$, you will have to know what *optimal* means here, what the function $R$ is, and possibly some information about $a$.

*Added:* As an example, suppose $R=wd$, $a$ is positive and you want to maximise the expectation $\mathbb{E}\left[aR-\frac{d^2-1}{2}\right]$.

Then the first derivative with respect to $d$ of the expectation is $\frac{a}{2}-d$, and the second derivative is negative, so the maximum occurs when $d=\frac{a}{2}$ in which case the expectation would be $\frac{a^2}{8} + \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: $R$ is a revenue from farm which is dependent upon weather and development program. hope this clears my question? Optimal means maximum here. $d$ is a development program cost. and $a$ is part of revenue given to workers.

Comment: Replacing $R$ with $wd$ does solve the problem but $R$ is not equal to $wd$ in this case its just a function of $wd$ it can take any form for example $3wd, 10wd$

Comment: If R is an increasing linear function of $wd$, say $R=bwd+k$ as in your examples, you will get optimal $d = \frac{ab}{2}$, i.e. much the same thing.

Comment: Thanks henry appreciate your help. Cheers